# C++ deleting a line of text from .txt file by first word

Tags: c++, text, delete-row

What my program needs to do is delete a line of text from .txt file but it needs to do so with user input. User says which line he wants to delete by typing first word and my program should delete the whole line eg.

[Image with example .txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoSfn.png)

User types opel and it should delete the line opel (astra).

```
string izbrisiLiniju;
string linija;

ifstream citanjeLinija;
citanjeLinija.open("auti.txt");

ofstream brisanjeLinija;
brisanjeLinija.open("temp.txt");

cout << "Ispis autiju" << endl;
while (getline(citanjeLinija, linija))
{
    cout << linija << endl;
}

cout << "Unesite vrstu automobila za izbrisati: " << endl;
getline(cin, izbrisiLiniju);

while (getline(citanjeLinija, linija))
{
    if (linija != izbrisiLiniju)
    {
        brisanjeLinija << linija << '\n';
    }
}

brisanjeLinija.close();
citanjeLinija.close();
remove("auti.txt");
rename("temp.txt", "auti.txt");

getchar();
```

Here is how i tried doing it but for some reason it just deletes every line.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Dont't post links to code. Show the code inline.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few bugs.

You compare the entire string, not just the prefix.

Replace `linija != izbrisiLiniju` with `linija.compare(0, izbrisiLiniju.size(), izbrisiLiniju) == 0`